# after_save callback to set the updated_by column to the current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to use an after_save callback to set the updated_by column to the current_user. But the current_user isn't available in the model. How should I do this?

Answer (score 8):

You need to handle it in the controller. First execute the save on the model, then if successful update the record field.

Example

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    if record.save
      record.update_attribute :updated_by, current_user.id
    end
  end
end
```

Another alternative (I prefer this one) is to create a custom method in your model that wraps the logic. For example

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  def save_by(user)
    self.updated_by = user.id
    self.save
  end
end

class MyController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    ...
    record.save_by(current_user)
  end
end
```

Comment: The reason for putting it in the model is that it is DRY, since save() can be called from many places in the app, not just one controller. I'd rather just do it once, and not have to repeat my self, and worry about always remembering to set this.

Comment: Then create a new method, like Model.save_from_user(user) and place there the logic to save the record and perform the touch. Then, in your controller simply call that method passing the `current_user` as argument.

Comment: Hi Simone, I have implemented the monkeypatch (as an answer below) based on your advice, as far as I could tell `touch` only does timestamps, not the users id. Do you see anything wrong with this? This is designed to work with a devise current_user. Greatly appreciate any input!

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this monkeypatch based on Simone Carletti's advice, as far as I could tell `touch` only does timestamps, not the users id. Is there anything wrong with this? This is designed to work with a devise `current_user`.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def save_with_user(user)
    self.updated_by_user = user unless user.blank?
    save
  end 

  def update_attributes_with_user(attributes, user)
    self.updated_by_user = user unless user.blank?
    update_attributes(attributes)
  end  
end
```

And then the `create` and `update` methods call these like so:

```
@foo.save_with_user(current_user)
@foo.update_attributes_with_user(params[:foo], current_user)
```