# How to get the current_user in a model observer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, observer-pattern

Given the following models:

```
Room (id, title)
RoomMembers (id, room_id)
RoomFeed, also an observer
```

When a Room title is updated, I want to create a RoomFeed item, showing who the user is who made the update.

```
@room.update_attributes(:title => "This is my new title")
```

Problem is in my observer for RoomFeed:

```
def after_update(record)
   # record is the Room object
end
```

The is no way for me to get the user.id of the person who just made the update. How do I go about doing that? is there a better way to do the update so I get the current_user?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167822/after-save-callback-to-set-the-updated-by-column-to-the-current-user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is, room.updated_by inside your observer. If you don't want to persist the updated_by, just declare it as an attr_accessor. Before you push the update, make sure you assign the current_user to updated_by, may be from you controller.

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical "separation of concern" issue.

The current_user lives in the controller and the Room model should know nothing about it. Maybe a RoomManager model could take care of who's changing the name on the doors...

Meanwhile a quick & dirty solution would be to throw a (non persistant) attribute at Room.rb to handle the current_user....

```
# room.rb
class Room
  attr_accessor :room_tagger_id
end
```

and pass your current_user in the params when updating @room.

That way you've got the culprit! :

```
def after_update(record)
   # record is the Room object
   current_user = record.room_tagger_id
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the following

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_current_user

  private
  def set_current_user
    User.current_user = #however you get the current user in your controllers
  end
end

class User
   ...
   def self.current_user
     @@current_user
   end
   def self.current_user= c
     @@current_user = c
   end
   ...
end
```

Then use...

```
User.current_user wherever you need to know who is logged in.
```

Remember that the value isn't guaranteed to be set when your class is called from non-web requests, like rake tasks, so you should check for `.nil?`

Comment: I like this solution, because this keeps the concerns separated nicely. The `Room` model does not need to know the current_user, and the observer can access it if needed. I use this exact approach myself as well. If the `current_user` is not set, I default to a SYSTEM user (e.g. so updates from within the console keep working, and are still clearly marked).

Comment: This is not a good idea because in production the values of the class variables will not be cleared between requests. Also this method isn't thread safe.

Comment: If you're doing this in a before filter then it should be executing at the beginning of every call, so you'd be ok in a Rails environment running with single threads per request.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a better approach

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models

Comment: Read the comments on that link. People are saying its a really bad idea to do such a thing as the next request might reuse the same user details you pass on to User.current.

Answer (score -3):

Update user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor :current
end
```

Update application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_current_user

  private
  def set_current_user
    User.current = current_user
  end
end
```

Then you can get logged user by `User.current` anywhere. I'm using this approach to access user exactly in observers.

Comment: cattr_accessor :current should be attr_accessor :current

Comment: @ajt no, it's a class attribute, that's why cattr

Comment: This is insane. You open yourself to 1) attacks where the next request reuse the old User.current of the previous requests 2) Let's not even talk about running a Threaded server 3) Prevent ActiveRecord from reloading its association cache properly when running in dev mode