# Creating associated resource by checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to have an Engineer be created by a checkbox in the Army form but it doesn't get created. The name of the checkbox is `siege` and is part of my `Army` model:

**models/army.rb**

```
class Army < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :siege
 attr_reader :siege
 validates_inclusion_of :siege, :in => [true, false]
 has_many :engineers

 def siege=(string_value)
   @siege = (string_value == '1')
 end
end
```

**models/engineer.rb**

```
class Engineer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :army
end
```

**armies/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @army do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :siege %>
  <%= f.submit "Create Army" %>
<% end %>
```

**controllers/armies_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @army = Army.new
end

def create
  @army = current_user.armies.build(params[:army])
    if @army.save
      redirect_to new_army_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

**models/army_observer.rb**

```
class ArmyObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_save(army)
    if army.siege
      Engineer.new({ :user_id => current_user.id, :army_id => :army_id })
    end
  end
end
```

The army gets created but the Engineer does not. What needs to be corrected in my code to enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving the record after initialing it :)

`.new` just builds a record does not save it.

In observer change `new` to `create!`

```
Engineer.new({ :user_id => current_user.id, :army_id => :army_id })
```

to

```
Engineer.create({ :user_id => current_user.id, :army_id => :army_id })
```

or else  save it after building the record

```
engineer= Engineer.new({ :user_id => current_user.id, :army_id => :army_id }) 
engneer.save
```

also you need to have your observer register in config to make it listen to activities

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#registering-observers

Comment: Something else is up because I got rid of the `if army.siege` and tried both of these and it still doesn't get created. I also tried making the `attr_accessible :army_id` but no good.

Comment: did you check ,is the call reaching the observer?

Comment: No it doesn't seem to be at all.

Comment: have you registered the observers to application config http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#registering-observers

Comment: Ok cool it started to work but I get this `undefined local variable or method `current_user` issue now. Any ideas?

Comment: current_user will not be accessible outside helpers,controller and views try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181036/how-to-get-the-current-user-in-a-model-observer

Comment: Thank you sir, I really appreciate the insight and help.