# Undefined local variable or method `current_user' for Observer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I've looked at a couple of questions about using `current_user` for an Observer and tried to implement what one said but its not working ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11845562/604023)).

I'm trying to create an engineer by my observer when the checkbox is marked true. An engineer and army belong to a user:

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor :current 
  has_many :armies
  has_many :engineers
end
```

**controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :set_time_zone, :set_current_user

  private

  def set_current_user
    User.current = current_user
  end
end
```

**models/army_observer.rb**

```
class ArmyObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_save(army)
    if army.siege
      Engineer.create({ :user_id => current_user.id, :army_id => :army_id })
    end
  end
end
```

With this code it gives me the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<ArmyObserver:0x4e68970>
```

Any other way? Maybe its conflicting with the Devise current_user method? Maybe Its better to keep the `current_user` in the controller? If so how would I do that?

Thanks just a newbie learning still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning Devise's `current_user` to the `User.current` class accessor precisely because it is not available on the model (and observer) level. So instead of trying to use `current_user` there, use the class accessor you just created:

```
Engineer.create({ :user_id => User.current.id, :army_id => :army_id })
```

EDIT:

BTW, I don't think this is thread safe - unless you also implement [the first part of this solution](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models) linked in one of the answers to the post you referenced.